# Is there a way to create a separator line in the screen?

Tags: windows

My laptop screen has a thick white vertical line that hides anything underneath it, is there any software that can create a line with a given thickness that would 
split the screen 
so instead of reading Sup__user, I read Sup__eruser, where the __ is the line crossing a word on the screen

EDIT

here's a picture of my screen:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture? Does the problem persist if you boot into another OS or go into your BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: It sounds like your screen is damaged. Any software will also appear behind it. I do not know any software/method that will put the screen into 2 sections and separate it so it can avoid that damaged part. It would be better to replace the screen.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I add a picture of the screen, please take a look. 
Can you please guide me through some troubleshooting that may help fixing it, or no way to fix?

Comment: I've started doing that...you need to answer the question I already asked.

Comment: how can I go into  BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: Open the start menu, click the power button, hold down Shift and click Restart. From there you can access the advanced menu and then UEFI settings (I can't remember exactly, I'm not at my laptop right now).